# AJAX multipart form never calls success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I submit a multipart form using ajax and it never calls the success function (although the form submit does succeed), it always redirects to the php page for the form.

This is my code:

```
 $('#pre-register-contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "preregisterform.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: false,
            data: new FormData($(this)),
            processData: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                    // Never reaches here!
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;
                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#pre-register-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#pre-register-contact-form')[0].reset();
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, if I don't submit the form in a multipart way, using the code below, it calls the success function:

```
$('#pre-register-contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "preregisterform.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#pre-register-contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#pre-register-contact-form')[0].reset();
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Nope, that doesn't talk about the success function not being called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change `$(this)` to `this` and then it worked

Comment: and that is what is exactly mentioned in the post i mentioned if you look down in the selected answer you will see `new FormData($(this)[0])` , try adding this statement `console.log(this, $(this), $(this)[0]);` inside the `onSubmit` event and notice that `this` and `$(this)[0]` are the same but not `$(this)` :) if you change your `this` to `$(this)[0]` it would still work, glad you fixed it cheers

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Should've posted that answer then instead of flagging my post

Comment: We should not copy/paste instead a similar or duplicate question that already has an answer is always preferred so other people having the same issue get redirected to the actual answer which has been undergone so many experts here and the comments on the answers also help you out, don't take it negatively neither I meant to discourage you but it was actually a solution suggested to you. Hope there are no harsh feelings, after all, me you and all the other members are here to help each other.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thank you, if you post your first comment as an answer I'll accept it for you :)